# Why would using head/tail instead of pattern matching make evaluation terminate?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation

As an exercise, I'm trying to define a `ruler` value

```
ruler :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
```

which corresponds to the ruler function

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2...
```

where the `n`'th element of the list (assuming the first element corresponds to `n=1`) is the largest power of 2 which evenly divides `n`. To make it more interesting, I'm trying to implement `ruler` without having to do any divisibility testing.

Using a helper function

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

which simply alternates the elements from the two given lists, I came up with this - but alas it doesn't work:

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave  (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
interleave  _      _      = []

ruler :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
ruler = foldr1 interleave . map repeat $ [0..]

main :: IO ()
main = print (take 20 ruler)
```

The program eventually uses up all stack space.

Now, what's strange is that the program works just fine if I adjust the definition of `interleave` so that it reads

```
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : head ys : interleave xs (tail ys)
```

I.e. I no longer use pattern matching on the second argument. Why does using `head` and `tail` here make `ruler` terminate - after all, the pattern matching is rather defensive (I only evaluate the first element of the list spine, no?).

Comment: I might be wrong, but head is partial, so the two functions are not equivalent : what if you call `interleave (1..) []` ?

Comment: @mb14: The `interleave _ _ = []` case is the same for either version, I only gave the alternative definition for the other case.

Comment: yes but in the head version, `interleave (x:xs) ys` branch is choosen and blows up on `head ys`

Comment: @mb14: That's right, I tried to find the smallest difference between the two `interleave` definitions which still triggers the difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are applying `foldr` with an strict combination function to an infinite list.

Boiled down to a minimal example, you can view this behaviour here:

```
*Main> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
*Main> :t flip seq
flip seq :: c -> a -> c
*Main> foldr1 const [0..]
0
*Main> foldr1 (flip seq) [0..]
^CInterrupted.
```

The fix is, as explained in other answers, to make `interleave` lazy.

More concretely, here is what happens. First we resolve the `foldr1`, replacing every `:` of the outer list with `interleave`:

```
foldr1 interleave [[0..], [1...], ...]
= interleave [0...] (interleave [1...] (...))
```

In order to make progress, the first `interleave` wants to evaluate the second argument before producing the first value.  But then the second wants to evaluate its second argument, and so on.

With the lazy definition of `interleave`, the first value is produced before evaluating the second argument. In particular, `interleave [1...] (...)` will evaluate to `1 : ...` (which helps the first `interleave` to make progress) *before* evaluating stuff further down.

Comment: +1 this is starting to make some sense, however I suppose you actually meant to write `foldr1 interleave [[0..], [1...], ...]
= interleave [0...] (foldr1 interleave [[1...], ...])` right?

Comment: No, I meant it this way. The `foldr` has disappeared in `...`. Clarified.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that pattern matching forces the first item in the spine, `head/tail` do not.

You could use *lazy* patterns to achieve the same goal:

```
interleave  (x:xs) ~(y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
```

Note the `~`: this is equivalent to defining `y` and `ys` using `head` and `tail`.

For example: the list below is undefined.

```
fix (\ (x:xs) -> 1:x:xs)
```

where `fix` is the fixed point combinator (e.g. from `Data.Function`). By comparison, this other list repeats `1` forever:

```
fix (\ ~(x:xs) -> 1:x:xs)
```

This is because the `1` is produced before the list is split between `x` and `xs`.

---

> Why forcing the first item in the spine triggers the problem?

When reasoning about a recursive equation such as

```
x = f x
```

it often helps to regard `x` as the value "approached" by the sequence of values

```
undefined
f undefined
f (f undefined)
f (f (f undefined))
...
```

(The above intuition can be made precise through a bit of denotational semantics and the Kleene's fixed point theorem.)

For instance, the equation

```
x = 1 : x
```

defines the "limit" of the sequence

```
undefined
1 : undefined
1 : 1 : undefined
...
```

which clearly converges to the repeated ones list.

When using pattern matching to define recursive values, the equation becomes, e.g.

```
(y:ys) = 1:y:ys
```

which, due to pattern matching, translates to

```
x = case x of (y:ys) -> 1:y:ys
```

Let us consider its approximating sequence

```
undefined
case undefined of (y:ys) -> ....   = undefined
case undefined of (y:ys) -> ....   = undefined
...
```

At the second step, the `case` diverges, making the result still `undefined`.
The sequence does not approach the intended "repeated ones" list, but is constantly `undefined`.

Using lazy patterns, instead

```
x = case x of ~(y:ys) -> 1:y:ys
```

we obtain the sequence

```
undefined
case undefined of ~(y:ys) -> 1:y:ys 
    = 1 : (case undefined of (y:_) -> y) : (case undefined of (_:ys) -> ys)
    = 1 : undefined : undefined      -- name this L1
case L1 of ~(y:ys) -> 1:y:ys
    = 1 : (case L1 of (y:_) -> y) : (case L1 of (_:ys) -> ys)
    = 1 : 1 : undefined : undefined  -- name this L2
case L2 of ~(y:ys) -> 1:y:ys
    = 1 : (case L2 of (y:_) -> y) : (case L2 of (_:ys) -> ys)
    = 1 : 1 : 1 : undefined : undefined
```

which does converge to the intended list. Note how lazy patterns are "pushed forward" without evaluating the `case` argument early. This is what makes them lazy. In this way, the `1` is produced before the pattern matching is performed, making the result of the recursively defined entity non trivial.

Comment: Why does forcing the first item in the spine trigger this problem?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I have edited my answer explaining this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is not so much about the pattern matching or using `head` and `tail`. The issue is how it's done, by defining your function as

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave  (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
interleave  _      _      = []
```

You're strictly pattern matching your arguments, that is, we need to know that they are lists of at least one element before we can choose the first branch. Since you're folding this function over an infinite list of lists, we can't really figure this out, and we run out of stack space.

To expand on this (to clarify things brought up in the comments), the first time we try to evaluate `interleave` (in `ruler`), we'd get something like

```
interleave (repeat 0) (foldr1 interleave (map repeat [1..]))
```

The first argument here of course matches the pattern, but to figure out if the second argument does, we have to try to evaluate it, so we get to

```
interleave (repeat 1) (foldr1 interleave (map repeat [2..]))
```

Now we can't evaluate this unless we know more about the second argument. Since the list `[2..]` never ends, this process can go on forever.

One solution to this is to do a lazy pattern binding on the second argument:

```
interleave  (x:xs) ~(y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
```

This acts like a promise that the second argument does match the pattern, so don't worry about it (of course this will fail if that isn't true). This means that that first evaluation of `interleave` can go on without looking deeper into the repeated fold, which in a domino-like effect solves the issue.

A sidenote is that your this version of `interleave` (as well as your head/tail version) will only work on lists where the second list is as long as or longer than the first.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't be able to figure this out"? The pattern "(x:xs)" matches any non-empty (even infinite) lists and should work just fine since only the first element of the list spine is evaluated, no? I suspect it has to do with the fact that I have a infinite list of infinite lists (which is what `map repeat [0..]` yields.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I guess the wording is a bit confusing. The problem isn't the infinite list that is being interleaved, but that you are folding an infinite list of (infinite) lists to interleave. The first call to interleave will go something like: `interleave (repeat 0) (foldr1 interleave (map repeat [1..]))`
To match the pattern `(y:ys)` we'd need to know if that continued fold has at least one element, but when we try, we just get back to the same problem, and since the list of lists (`map repeat [0..]`) is infinite, the process is infinite.

Comment: The wording is indeed confusing. The statement ”we need to know that it is a list of at least one element before we can choose the first branch. Since your folding this function over an infinite list, it won't be able to figure this out,” is simply not true.

Comment: I tried, but failed, to use more accessible language :) but isn't that what this case boils down to? The pattern matching makes the function strict in the second argument, so the infinite fold can't stop?

Comment: I think there are many lists around (the argument to `interleave`, and the list that `interleave` is folded over). Re-reading  it again it makes some sense now...

Comment: Yeah, I edited the answer, I hope it's clearer what I meant now :)